# Sum up all values from all numpy subarray of different shape inside an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy.array of numpy arrays of different shapes.
When I call np.sum(my_array) I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (13,5) (5,3)
```

All I want is sum of all values across all arrays like sum(my_array) = some float number

Is there some parameter that I missed or another method?
I can only think of something like this

```
np.sum([np.sum(a) for a in my_array])
```

Is this an optimal way?

**Update:**

```
print(type(my_array))
print((my_array).shape)
print([(type(sub_array), sub_array.shape) for sub_array in my_array])
```

output:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(2,)
[(<class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (13, 5)), (<class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (5, 3))]
```

Comment: What is `my_array`? Is it a python list containing numpy arrays?

Comment: @jozzas It's also a numpy.array

Comment: What kind of ndarray is this that contains other ndarrays of varying shapes?  Please print the results of `type(my_array)` for us.

Comment: @ballsdotballs I've updated the post above with an output.

Comment: TIL that you can have ndarrays with dtype 'object' whose elements can be arbitrary shapes and types.

Answer (score 4):

Using a generator should be better in most cases:

```
np.sum(np.sum(a) for a in my_array)
```

Without the '[ ... ]' you don't create a list.

```
%timeit np.sum( np.sum(a) for a in my_array )
```

100000 loops, best of 3: 5.73 µs per loop

```
%timeit np.sum( [np.sum(a) for a in my_array] )
```

100000 loops, best of 3: 9.97 µs per loop

Comment: Wow. Didn't know that I can omit '[..]' thanks. How do you make this %timeit? I've tried it but couldn't make it work like yours. Please, can you tell or post a link?

Comment: I wrote this in a IPython Notebook. You should take a look at that, it is included when installing python with anaconda or enthougt. %timeit can be used there.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = np.array(map(np.arange, range(16, 32)))

Eyy![28]: %timeit np.sum(map(np.sum, a))
10000 loops, best of 3: 90.5 µs per loop

Eyy![29]: %timeit np.sum(np.sum(b) for b in a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 86 µs per loop

Eyy![30]: %timeit np.sum([np.sum(b) for b in a])
10000 loops, best of 3: 90.2 µs per loop
```

also note that many times it can be easier to just have zeropadded numpy arrays if you know the maximum size in advance.